# Do we need an iPhone/iPad for its development?

Tags: iphone, ipad

Today i was going through an website and found something over this iphone and ipad development projects. I had a question whether a developer requires an iphone to actually work with or is there any other simulator type device where we can test it out too.

It would be also great if you can share some docs on getting started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have applications that run without a problem on the simulator and crash on the device, so I'd say yes. You might delay it for a bit, and work on the main aspects and buy the device later, but you should have it.

You should start at the [iPhone Dev center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) and depending on your knowledge of Objective C, try some tutorials for it. One of the first tutorials I read about Objective C, and which helped me a lot, is [here](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)

You can simulate certain gestures and actions while running the simulator: the developer.apple article is [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/125-Using_iPhone_Simulator/iphone_simulator_application.html)

Answer (score 6):

You can test many aspects without having an iPad.

There are, however, some that you cannot.

- Touch
- Acceleration sensor
- 3G internet
- much more

I strongly recommend buying an iPad / iPhone to test the user interface. A PC and the iPad have very different user interaction models, it's hard to create a native feeling app without having an actual device.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think there are any devices that run the iPhone system. If there are they are probably illegal.

There is emulator build in XCode.

You dont need a device to run your code etc, but try to test the touch and other sensors in the emulator.

So basically if you are planning on shipping something bigger than helloworld you probably should get the Apple device.

Answer (score 2):

You can develop with the iPhone SDK which include an emulator. http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action but you would probably be better off having one of the devices if your developing a complex application. For working with Camera's or sensors it's best to have a real device to test you code on.

Answer (score 1):

There must be an emulator (I'm not sure, that's a guess), but as with any other development you better have a real device as well so that you have better chances of reproducing problems customers will report.

Answer (score 1):

For iPad development you must have Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard